# Seeing if one line from file is a duplicate in another file Python

Tags: python

I am trying to search filetwos contents and see if it contains any duplicates of the given search term(line from fileone). If it contains a duplicate it will do nothing but if it contains no duplicates I want it to append a line.

**fileone.txt** (two lines)

```
[('123', 'aaa')]

[('900', 'abc')]
```

**filetwo.txt**

```
[('123', 'aaa')]

[('999', 'zzz')]
```

My code below adds the lines to filetwo even if they are duplicates. I cannot figure this out!

```
with open('fileone.txt', 'r') as f:
seen = open('filetwo.txt', 'a+')
for line in f:
    if line in seen:
        print(line + 'is a duplicate')
    else:
        seen.write(line)

f.close()
seen.close()
```

Comment: As a side note: You don't need to—and shouldn't—do `f.close()` after `with open(…) as f:`. That's the whole point of a `with` statement. And it's clearer if you handle both files the same way, instead of one with a `with` and the other without.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just do `if line in seen:` to search the whole `seen` file for the given line. Even if you could, it would only search the rest of the file, and since you're at the end of the file, that would mean you're searching over nothing. And, even if you solved that problem, it would still require doing a linear search over the whole file for each line, which would be very slow.

The simplest thing to do is to keep track of all the lines seen, e.g., with a `set`:

```
with open('filetwo.txt') as f:
    seen = set(f)

with open('fileone.txt') as fin, open('filetwo.txt', 'a+') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line in seen:
            print(line + 'is a duplicate')
        else:
            fout.write(line)
            seen.add(line)
```

Notice that I'm pre-filling `seen` with all of the lines in `filetwo.txt` before we start, and then adding each new line to `seen` as we go along. That avoids having to re-read `filetwo.txt` over and over again—we know what we're writing to it, so just remember it.